# .run file not running

Tags: 14.04

I have recently tried to update my nividia graphics driver by downloading it from the nividia website. The file is a .run , therefore I did the ordinary graphical method of allowing it to execute by going into file properties and clicking on the allow to execute box. Yet ubuntu still tries to open it with my text editor. With limited knowledge of ubuntu I tried to use terminal but was unsuccessful.

I run ubuntu gnome and my system is 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try going into your additional drivers in unity start menu? Press super key (Windows key)  or click the launcher in the top left corner and type 'additional' 
It should bring up additional drivers.  Choose the nvidia proprietary, enter your password and follow prompts.

Answer (score 0):

## Running a `.run` file

1. `sudo chmod +x <file name>.run`.
2. `sudo ./<file name>.run`.

### Alternatively

1. [image: Right click the file icon and select 'Properties'.]
2. [image: Select 'Allow executing file as program' in 'Permissions' tab.]
3. Try opening as any regular file.

## Nvidia drivers

I personally recommend installing them from `ppa` as described here: http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in.html .
`ppa` to add: `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`.